# StreamSocketListener doesn’t listens on all adapters of Windows Phone 8.1 Simulator

Tags: networking, tcp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

I have `StreamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync( "11111" )` call in my WP 8.1 WinRT app, and another `StreamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync( "22222" )` in my CodedUI test running on the same simulator.

The behavior of those 2 calls differs dramatically, here’s the nmap port scan of my emulator’s IP addresses:

```
Nmap scan report for 169.254.26.186 (="Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch")
22222/tcp open     unknown
11111/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap scan report for 169.254.80.80
22222/tcp filtered unknown
11111/tcp open     unknown

Nmap scan report for Mah-PC (192.168.1.175)
22222/tcp filtered unknown
11111/tcp open     unknown

Nmap scan report for 192.168.33.1
22222/tcp filtered unknown
11111/tcp open     unknown
```

The “filtered” ports are really closed, i.e. my client fails to connect to those ports.

The documentation for BindServiceNameAsync variant I’m using says “method binds to the local IP addresses of **all network interfaces on the local computer**”. Is there a way to make it work as advertised?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a CodedUI test? How does it differ from a WinRT app?

Comment: CodedUI is GUI test framework included in some visual studio SKUs. It only works on simulators or on developer-unlocked devices.

A test runs on the device in some background process that has no UI. It uses UI Automation COM API to interact with whatever application running on the device.